# How to get lost focus event in GWT

Tags: gwt

I have a `TextBox`, and I want to do something with content after box will lose focus.
in older versions of GWT I could use `FocusListener` (it has methods `onFocus` and `onLostFocus`). But t is deprecated and replaced by `FocusHandler`.
Is `FocusHandler` can handle lost focus event? and how I can distinguish them from onFocus?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As always, [the javadoc](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusListener.html#onLostFocus-com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget-) points to the replacement class(es), in this case `BlurHandler`.

Comment: I realize this is a very old article, but the link is no longer valid which is why I suppose stackoverlfow always suggests not just providing a link to another web page.  :)

Comment: Link fixed to new javadoc location

Answer (score 8):

In GWT we use `BlurHandler` for focus lost, such as below:

```java
textBox.addBlurHandler(new BlurHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onBlur(BlurEvent event) {
        // Your Code
    }
});
```